# Can't access any website when connected to pptp vpn

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, pptp

## Server for test:

***Server based in China can't access Gooogle,Facebook,Instagram,Twitter, but you can try to use it test connection to stackoverflow***

```
ip: 132.232.70.189
account: yunaqi
password: qishi
```

## What I did on my server:

install pptp

```
sudo yum -y install pptpd
```

edit  sysctl.conf

```
vi /etc/sysctl.conf
```

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

edit pptpd.conf

```
vi /etc/pptpd.conf
```

```
localip 192.168.0.1
remoteip remoteip 192.168.0.234-238,192.168.0.245
```

edit chap-secrets

```
vi /etc/ppp/chap-secrets
```

```
yuanqi  * qishi *
```

config iptables

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p gre -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 47 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.1/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

start pptp

```
systemctl enable pptpd.service
systemctl start pptpd.service
```

That's all, I don't kown which step is wrong.Please help me.

Comment: did you add dns servers at /etc/ppp/pptpd.options?

Comment: No,i didn't. Now I edit /etc/ppp/options like this:ms-dns 8.8.8.8, but it still don't work out.